# Bootstrap table text doesnt fit

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

I have bootstrap table that looks like this:

[image]

As you can see the first column's text doesn't fit. How can I make first column text fit the column ?

Here's the code:

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="portlet light ">
                <div class="portlet-body">
                    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-checkable order-column" id="matches_table">
                        <tbody>
                            {% for field, value in object.items %}
                            <tr class="odd gradeX">
                                <td width=""><b>{{ field|field_name_split|title }}</b></td>
                                <td width="">{{ value }}</td>
                            </tr>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Your code, don't have the . Below I have added a sample table bootstrap code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <h2>Hover Rows</h2>
            <p>The .table-hover class enables a hover state (grey background on mouse over) on table rows:</p>            
            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-checkable order-column">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>Firstname</th>
                    <th>Lastname</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td>John</td>
                    <td>Doe</td>
                    <td>john@example.com</td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks,